# Angular + Material can't use derectives in dialogs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

This is the dialog content

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <form>
        <h1>New Shipment</h1>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <select #shipmentStatusd name="cars" class="form-control">
                <div *ngFor="let status of shipmentStatuses">{{status}}</div>
            </select>
            <label class="form-label">shipmentStatus</label>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

In the component.ts of the dialog, I have this variable

```
 shipmentStatuses = ["INITIATED", "SENT", "ARRIVED", "DELIVERED"];
```

This is my app module (I have only one)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CompaniesComponent,
    OfficesComponent,
    ShipmentsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get this error

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I really have no idea what is going on, I also can't use ngModel in the dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add the dialog components in module declarations and in the module entryComponents. I have no idea why its not mentioned anywhere.